# OpenERP only available through localhost

Tags: apache, networking, odoo

i installed openerp on ubuntu (virtual machine) through the package-manager. On localhost i can access Openerp very well and there are no problems. When i try to access it throuh my internal network i get no connection to openerp.

nmap shows me no open ports on 8096. Apache works well even outside of the VM and i can access different apache sites without any problems.

Perhaps the interface was stored somewhere because i had to change this for the new VM host. The firewall is not the problem.

my openerp-server.conf looks very tiny too...

===== logfile ====

```
2013-10-02 11:17:29,878 26497 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 6.1-1
2013-10-02 11:17:29,879 26497 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: /usr/share/openerp/addons
2013-10-02 11:17:29,879 26497 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2013-10-02 11:17:29,879 26497 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2013-10-02 11:17:29,879 26497 INFO ? openerp: database user: openerp
2013-10-02 11:17:29,880 26497 INFO ? openerp.service.netrpc_server: starting NET-RPC service on 0.0.0.0:8070
2013-10-02 11:17:29,881 26497 INFO ? openerp.netsvc: Starting 1 services
2013-10-02 11:17:30,213 26497 INFO ? openerp.addons.web: embedded mode
2013-10-02 11:17:30,234 26497 INFO ? openerp.wsgi.core: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2013-10-02 11:17:31,137 26497 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the standard OpenERP 6.1 ubuntu package, the default is to listen on `0.0.0.0` (all interfaces) unless you've overriden the `xmlrpc_interface` config setting explicitly.

You can check the logfile (by default in `/var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log`) and look for the openerp startup lines, you should see something that looks like this:

```
    openerp.wsgi.core: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
```

You can force `xmlrpc_interface = 0.0.0.0` in your configuration file (`/etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf) but that should be the default already.

The `--xmlrpc-interface` can also be specified as a command-line option when launching the server, but if you're using the standard ubuntu packages it should not be present.

If the log indicates that after a full restart OpenERP is really listening to `0.0.0.0`, then you should double-check for VM networking config issues, firewalls, etc.

Comment: it seems that the configuration of the OpenERP is OK. The firewall is also not the problem. It must be something with the network-settings. on localhost i can OpenERP only with 'localhost:8096' but not with '196.168.1.xxx:8096'. Sorry for that questions but i am not used to network-configs